# ERROR: "This document requires at least Xcode 12.0"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xcode12

Opened a project in `Xcode 12.0` that I started on `Xcode 11.x` the other day.  Without thinking, I made some edits in the interface builder and when I opened the project back up in Xcode 11.6 I got the `This document requires at least Xcode 12.0.` error.  I can't build the project or open the main storyboard file.

Any thoughts on what I can remove to open/build this project in Xcode 11.6?
The recovery suggestion is `Recovery Suggestion: This version does not support image references. Open this document with at least Xcode 12.0.`, but I'm not sure what that means or where to look.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Comment: Do you have your project in version control? You should just roll back to the latest working commit. If not, you should open the storyboard with a text editor and edit out the changes that look like they were added by Xcode 12.

Comment: Open the project in Xcode 12 and set the storyboard file version to Xcode 11.

Comment: don't know why this question got negative votes. Although its a valid question. I also faced this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the two suggestions!  Turns out the issue didn't originate from the storyboard, although that's where the error was being thrown.  Instead it was caused by a `navigationItem` image that I was setting programmatically in one of the project's `ViewController` files.  The icon ended up being exclusive to `iOS 14+`, which was why the project wouldn't build in `Xcode 11.6`.

I switched the icon and everything built without issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue while loading another author's project. The solution that worked for me was to open Main.storyboard in a text editor such as Sublime and change the line:

```
<capability name="Image references" minToolsVersion="12.0"/>
```

to

```
<capability name="Image references" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
```

I was able to build successfully after this and there was no error.

Comment: This may cause some builtin image symbols couldn't be found in lower Xcode when running or archiving.

Answer (score 1):

To run your project with previous Xcode versions, try the following:

- Open the affected .storyboard file with an external editor (i.e. TextEdit, TextWrangler or any other..)
- Search in the xml document for all keys "minToolsVersion"
- If you find some key with value `minToolsVersion="12.0"`downgrade it manually to be compilant with your XCode version.
- Save the file and come back to XCode

Now the error should be disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Select your storyboard > Right Click > Open As > Source code > Search for this key "minToolsVersion" from there you need to decrease your version as per your xcode.

[image]